# How to display an image in every page of a table in MIcrosoft Report rdlc

Tags: reportviewer

I was wondering if anyone has an idea of how to display an image in every page of a Microsoft Report rdlc that has a table.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 ultimate, c#, asp.net 4.5, sql 2008

This is a very simple report: ReportS4.rdlc
It has one image at the top of the body, (not a header) and a tablix after it.

Everything works fine, except the image is only displayed in the first page of the report.

I tried setting the RepeatWith to the tablix id with no success.

Thanks for the help

rubenc

Comment: why don't you just use header? What's the reason not using it?

Comment: because the image is in the middle of the body

Comment: In your question, you mentioned it's at the top of the body. If the image is at the top of body, moving it to header will not cause any visual difference. Could you explain more?

Comment: ok, the image is a form that Im filling in with the table, I tried usisng it as a backgroud image of the tablix but there is no setting to fit proportionally, but if i use an Image object it looks so perfect and nice, except only in the first page, if I could only make it visible in every page...